# How to get a 3D camera 'following' the character position side-by-side

Tags: 3d, camera, godot

I'm using the 'classic' target/pos/offset solution to have a 3D camera following my racing character.

The camera is following it, but I believe it would have a better effect if the camera was by its side (or even leading it, looking back).

I tried to tweak the classic code, adding vectors to the final 'pos' and even just using the target's origin to set the camera's one with no different result.

Is this an engine/object limitation (only being able to follow) or is there a code that would keep the camera by its target side (or at any other fixed position relative to it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the classic way to have the camera follow an object in Godot, is simply to make the `Camera` node a child of the node you want it to follow, and then position it relative to it in the editor, no code needed. If anything, I'd call that the classic solution.

---

If you want the camera to avoid getting inside objects, you have two options: `ClippedCamera` and `SpringArm`. The difference? `SpringArm` will allow obstacle between it and its parent, while `ClippedCamera` won't.

To use `ClippedCamera`, try changing the `Camera` node to a `ClippedCamera` (and add colliders to what you want it to avoid). I suggest setting the process mode of the `ClippedCamera` to `Idle`.

Alternatively, use the `SpringArm` node. Set it the same way you'd se the camera (child to what you want follow, positioned relative to it), then make the `Camera` a child of the `SpringArm`.

Note: `ClippedCamera` can result in some jarring jumps when something gets between it and its parent. Instead, I suggest to use `SpringArm` and add Proximity fade to your spatial materials, so they fade out when they are too close to the camera, and thus they do not occlude the player view. *You may also not use `SpringArm` at all, and rely on proximity fade only. But that is a game by game decision.*

---

If you want to only follow the position, but not the rotation, you can use a `RemoteTransform` node. Add the `RemoteTransform` as a child of what you want to follow, then configure it (in the inspector panel in the editor) to push the the position to another node. And, of course, that node is the `Camera`.